# Ionic view app - Facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, cordova, oauth-2.0, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have tried several things to make facebook authentication work with Ionic View app OR phonegap developer app.

None of them worked.

Finally i tried this:
 - created and hosted a URL on a server. lets say abc.com
 - when user tries to login via facebook, i redirect user to this URL. then abc.com redirects user to facebook, user logs in, facebook redirect back to abc.com (i configured this as return URL), gets the token, make http request to get the user data and i am all set. 
 -THE PROBLEM : How to redirect user from this abc.com BACK TO IONIC APP??

I tried redirecting back to the file path (file:\var...), it didn't work. 
Any thoughts?

Or any other way to make facebook oauth work with ionic view?

Comment: Are you using cordovaOauth plugin? the http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/

Comment: Yes!! I have finally got it working. Realized that its just the problem with ionic view, Works flawlessly on compiled app